# What are the different ways to format Ballerina code

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, formatter, ballerina

I want to format my Ballerina code. What are the tools/methods that I can use to format? Also, are there any formatting guidelines to format Ballerina code?

Answer (score 2):

Ballerina code can be formatted using,

1. Ballerina VSCode plugin
2. `bal format` command

The Ballerina community encourages the following coding conventions.
https://ballerina.io/learn/style-guide/coding-conventions/

However, the Ballerina team is yet to introduce a formatting specification/configuration.